Using Mockito instead of ByteBuddy for method interception in Production
My project requires me to intercept methods of a variety of classes and methods.
I figured out there are at least 2 ways to implement:

Using ByteBuddy's intercept, creating a subclass on all objects.

Using Mockito's InvocationOnMock on defaultAnswer, and returning a mock of all objects.


So far I prefer Mockito. It takes care of inner classes/private classes/anonymous classes nicely, where using byte buddy, I keep looking for solutions for calling the constructors etc.
I was just wondering if there are any risks using Mockito in my production code.

What are you trying to do? Why would you use a test framework in production code? This sounds like you have a really broken code base. Messing with some internals of your code base will make it much harder to understand and maintain. I'd look into refactoring so that you don't need these crutches anymore.

It would be very unexpected to use a test framework like Mockito in production, and Mockito's focus on testing means it may do so at the expense of security or performance. It'd be hard to be concrete about this without knowing exactly what you're implementing, but I would look through a lot of other options (Guice AOP, Spring AOP, raw Java proxies, refactoring) before going with Mockito in production.
